# Conjectures about zeta functions and poles

Tags: complex-analysis, prime-numbers, zeta-functions, euler-product

Let $p^*_n$ be the $n$ th element of a subset of primes such that $p^*_{n+1}>p^*_n$ and $p^*_n < O((n+2) ln((n+2))^3)$. Define $f(z)$ as the analytic continuation of $\prod_{n>0} (1+\dfrac{1}{p^{*^z}_n-1})$.

The analytic continuation is to the largest possible domain.
If there is no natural boundary then this is the entire complex plane.

**Conjecture 1 :** The analytic continuation to the entire complex plane Always exists.

**Conjecture 2 :** If $f(1)$ is a pole then it is the only pole in the complex plane $C$ of $f(z)$.

It is easy to show for $Re(z) > 1$ but is the conjecture true ??

Notice $f(1)$ is not Always a pole see :

[Assuming there exist infinite prime twins does $\prod_i (1+\frac{1}{p_i})$ diverge?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/483880/assuming-there-exist-infinite-prime-twins-does-prod-i-1-frac1p-i-diver)

Comment: How do you know your function has an analytic continuation? and, continuation to what domain?

Comment: @GerryMyerson those are additional questions. I meant the largest possible continuation , ideally to the whole complex plane.

Comment: I made an edit.